# 3D char array getting different amount of columns per row C++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
   int main()
{
    char tabla[15][4][20];
    strcpy(tabla[0][0], "ABC");
    strcpy(tabla[0][1], "123");
    strcpy(tabla[0][2], "444");
    strcpy(tabla[0][3], "1405");

    return 0;
}
```

when i debug i not only find that tabla[0][3] hasnt been copied correctly but i also noticed that not every row of the array has the same amount of columns. For example tabla[0] has tabla[0][0], tabla[0][1] and tabla[0][2] but tabla[4] just have tabla[4][0] and tabla[4][1]. Why am i not getting 3 columns per row?? Is there any error on my code?

Comment: Every row in the array has the same number of columns, but since the entire array has not been initialized it contains random garbage, and this is just how your debugger is displaying char data that's mostly random garbage. Additionally, if your intent is to write C++ code, then you should write C++ code using `std::vector`s and `std::string`s, instead of plain arrays and C library functions like `strcpy`.

Comment: It works for me: https://onlinegdb.com/UfQUjMeuW

Comment: *Why am i not getting 3 columns per row?* Because you asked for 4?

Comment: But seriously, What debugger are you using? is it being fronted by an IDE?

Comment: Im using codeblocks, im a studend and i was told to use it

Comment: When I use GDB with his program and try to print tabla at the return statement GDB freaks out and prints mostly rubbish.  But If I clear the variable by declaring it as `char tabla[15][4][20] = {};` then GDB prints `{{"ABC", '\000' <repeats 16 times>, "123", '\000' <repeats 16 times>, "444", '\000' <repeats 16 times>, "1405", '\000' <repeats 15 times>}, { '\000' <repeats 19 times>, '\000' <repeats 19 times>, '\000' <repeats 19 times>, '\000' <repeats 19 times>} <repeats 14 times>}` which is right.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah ive tried that but i think i keep getting the same

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It actually worked, thanksss

Comment: You have `15` `4 x 20` arrays. Or another way to look at it is you have `15` arrays where each element holds `4` arrays of `20` characters each.